# Android studio add file for debug build

Tags: android, android-studio

How add some file only for debug build in Android studio? Like [this](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/tree/dev-hilt/app/src/debug/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp). I added by hand in debug folder but android studio can't see it in adnroid project.

UPD: solve problem with studio visibility. You need put file exactly the same way in main source. In example it "architecture-samples\app\src\debug\java\com\example\android\architecture\blueprints\todoapp". But i will be appreciate it if smb know how do it not by handle

[image: How add some file only for debug build]